# Mesa and nvidia conflict

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, chroot

I am quite new to Linux.  I have spent hours searching through forums for the answer.

I'm using Arch Linux and am unable to update the system now as I keep getting an error telling me that Mesa-libgl and nvidia-libgl are in conflict.  I attempted to fix this with `sudo pacman -S nvidia nvidia-libgl`.

When I rebooted I just got a black screen that had some info and it would just hang there and never load GNOME.  I just want to re-install `mesa` and `mesa-libgl`.

I `chroot` in from GRUB and it puts me as root@(none).  `pacman -S mesa mesa-libgl` just gives me could not resolve host on all my mirrors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue.  I was able to boot console mode using <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.  From there I just installed what I needed.  Thank you for your time.